# Viewing items bought more than 60 days ago in eBay

Tags: ebay

Does anyone know if it is possible to view items I bough more than 60 days ago on eBay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see *replies* 1 and 5 here: http://forums.ebay.com/db2/topic/My-Ebay/Viewing-Past-Orders/520189127&start=0

---

**Reply number 1:** There isn't any way to do that on eBay at present. You can, however, go over to PayPal and look up your history.

---

**Reply number 5:** We are working on a new feature that will let you see purchases from the last three years. We are just now opening it to a small test group for feedback and are not yet sure whether we will launch it to a wider audience.

One of the feedback channels will be through this forum--in fact, I'll just use this thread!! The group from this channel will be limited to 25. If you'd like to be in that test group, please reply in this thread and I will add you assuming we are still under 25 (we are now).

Here's what you'll see if you sign up for the test group:

To see purchases for the last three years, go to either the Won page or the All Buying page. Then scroll to the bottom of the Won container. Under the pagination area, you will see the link called "Go to past purchases," like the one shown here.

The most recent 60 days are still shown in the Won container. The purchases from day 61 to the last three years are on the Past Purchases page. There are currently no item images available.

The feedback I'm looking for is:

- How useful is this feature?
- Do you have general comments about the display?

Like I said, we have a small test group started, but if anyone else would like to join (up until the 25 limit), please let me know in this thread. I will use the user ID from your reply.

Comment: There are 100 + replies. Are you talking about replies 1 and 5? Please quote the relevant portions for your answer to make it easier for users.

Comment: sorry, I was talking about replies 1 and 5... updated the answer per your guidelines